# User fgetcsv with and without quotations around entries

Tags: php

**Edit:** is there an alternative to fgetcsv?

The code below processes csv files where each entry is in cased by **quotes** and separated by **commas** `ex: "Name","Last"`... the problem I'm having is sometimes the csv files do not have quotes around each entry and just has the comma to separate it `ex: Name,Last`. How can I handle both types?

```
$uploadcsv = "/temp/files/Load15.csv";
       $handle = fopen($uploadcsv, 'r');
       $column_headers = array();
$row_count = 0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  if ($row_count==0){
    $column_headers = $data;
  } else {
    print_r($data);
  }
  ++$row_count;
}
```

**this csv works:**

```
"Name","Last"
"Mike","Aidens"
"Mike1","Aidens1"
```

**this csv does not work:**

```
Name,Last
Mike,Aidens
Mike1,Aidens1
```

**Edit:** Strange error... I tried a small snippet from the CSV file with no quotations and it worked. Odd then, I try a large piece then the entire CSV content (this is all be paste into a new test.csv file) and it worked. Both files are the same exact size 17,151kb yet the original csv file will not process. There is no trailing spaces or line at the end.

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't handle both right now? What happens instead? fgetcsv handled unquoted values for me.

Comment: @dan nothing happens not error and nothing is output. it only works with "Name" and won't work with Name. I need for it to work with "Name","Last" and Name,Last

Comment: Provide your CSV file, because fgetcsv is not at fault

Comment: @Dan I've updated with an example

Comment: I just ran your code on your example CSV, and it printed the two rows on my screen. There is no bug here, there has to be more to your setup.

Comment: @Dan I added an Edit to my original post. Is there any reason why i'm experiencing this problem. I took the content from the original csv and pasted it in a new blank file and it worked. Any idea why this would be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Set the 4th parameter to an empty string, it sets the enclosure, which is default `"`.

```
fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",", '');
```

Comment: i thought this would work, but not.. does this line automatically encompass the field with quote mark?

Comment: Yields the error `Error : fgetcsv(): enclosure must be a character`

Answer (score 1):

Use this line of code before php getcsv function call

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the CSV file is malformed, this will "just work".

In order words, you don't need to worry about whether or not every field has quotes around it, [fgetcsv](http://www.php.net/fgetcsv) will take care of this for you.

Comment: correct it works from with "Name","Last" like in my code above but I need for Name,Last to be detected and processed as well. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure your CSV file isn't malformed (has a missing or extra comma or question mark) - fgetcsv should cope with this correctly.

Comment: please see my Edit comments in original post. strange issue

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, it couldn't read Hebrew (utf-8) letters without double quotes. It ran fine on the command line (could read Hebrew without double quotes), but in Apache it read only the header which had double quotes and returned empty strings instead of Hebrew strings in the rest of the lines which did not have double quotes at all.

Checked the locale in Apache and it returned the letter "C", but in the command line it returned "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C;LC_COLLATE=C;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_MESSAGES=C;LC_PAPER=C;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=C;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"

Thus I've added the following line before the fgetcsv command:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF-8');
```

And it worked, and read Hebrew letters without double quotes successfully.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I am aware `fgetcsv` should work fine with or without quotes around the data.